# How to Make an Ordinary Page Border Resemble This Tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox, page, border, crop, frame

I know that I can produce (ordinary) page borders, for example, as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=.75in,paperwidth=16cm,paperheight=24cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[a4,frame,noinfo,center]{crop}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\parskip 10pt
\large
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

[image]

However,

I would like the above page borders to resemble the following `tcolorbox`, which, as one can see, is not a page border:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=.75in,paperwidth=16cm,paperheight=24cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\tcbset{
    Baystyle/.style={
        %sharp corners,
        enhanced,
        boxrule=6pt,
        colframe=green!35!black,
        height=\textheight,
        width=\textwidth,
        borderline={6pt}{-11pt}{},
    }
}
\begin{document}
\large
\begin{tcolorbox}[Baystyle]
\lipsum
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

QUESTION: How may I modify the first set of code so that the page border it produces resembles the  border of the indicated `tcolorbox`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `tikzpagenodes` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=.75in,paperwidth=16cm,paperheight=24cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage[a4,frame,noinfo,center]{crop}


\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\AddToHook{shipout/background}{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[green!50!black,rounded corners,ultra thick] ([xshift=-0.3cm,yshift=-0.3cm]current page text area.south west) rectangle ([xshift=0.3cm,yshift=0.3cm]current page text area.north east);
\draw[red!50!black,rounded corners,ultra thick] ([xshift=-0.5cm,yshift=-0.5cm]current page text area.south west) rectangle ([xshift=0.5cm,yshift=0.5cm]current page text area.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\parskip 10pt
\large
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When I tried running your code, I got an error on my end. The `\AddToHook` seems to have caused it. So, after removing it, and well as the opening and closing braces around the begin and end `tikzpicture`, and placing the `tikzpicture` immediately after `\begin{document}`--- I was able to produce your displayed output. However, the rest of the lipsum text appeared on the next page without the double page border. For people like me who have trouble with `\AddToHook`---is there a way to modify your code so that the border envelops all of the text over multiple pages?

Comment: If `\AddToHook` doesn't work, your tex distribution might be outdated, this was added last year so so. Which version do you have?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it is definitely more than a year old.

Comment: Then the solution is simple: update :) Are you using texlive or miktex?

Comment: I believe that I am using texlive.

Comment: Then you can install the current version texlive2022 from https://tug.org/texlive/

Comment: Thank you for providing the link. Quick question if I may: Do I need to uninstall my current version, or should this link allow me to "write over" my current installation?

Comment: You can have multiple versions of texlive installed in parallel. They will each be installed in its own folder. Depending on how much free space you have, you can decide if you just want to keep them or if you want to delete the old one once you are sure that the new one works fine.

Comment: Thank you for this helpful information.

Comment: You're welcome!